# Weakening of orbit type stratification to non-proper Lie group actions

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups

I am working in a setting where I am thinking about effective, fixed-point free actions of $\text{PSL}(2; \mathbb{R})$ on compact three manifolds by homeomorphisms. I'm not sure if this is relevant context, but the actions I am interested in arise as restrictions of an action of $\text{Homeo}_0(S^1)$ and are generally *not proper*.

The theory of proper Lie group actions in the smooth category seems to be very well-understood, and, in particular, the orbit type stratification theorem is a powerful result. So my questions are the following:

1. Is there some kind of weakening of the orbit type stratification that remains true for non-proper actions by finite-dimensional Lie groups on manifolds in low dimensions in the topological category? *(for example, even just knowing here that the collection of the orbits remains locally finite would be very useful to me)*
2. Is there some well-developed theory here that I am overlooking in my literature search or are most results in this direction fairly ad hoc? *(and rather than look to the literature for a general answer, I would be better off trying to devise an answer in my particular setting?)*

Looking forward to hearing folks' thoughts on this! Reference suggestions are more than welcome.